# Automating install of a mix of conda-forge and pip python libraries

Tags: python, pip, conda-forge

I have a python package for which I need some other python libraries that are installed via conda-forge. However, it also needs a small number of libraries that are installed via pip. What is the best way to automate the installation of this mix of conda-forge and pip libraries when someone installs my package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conda's `environment.yml` file can take both conda dependencies and pip dependencies. I'll paste in from the [docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-file-manually):

```
name: stats2
channels:
  - javascript
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - bokeh=2.4.2
  - numpy=1.21.*
  - nodejs=16.13.*
  - flask
  - pip
  - pip:
    - Flask-Testing
```

The `pip` array at the end lists stuff you'd like to pull from PyPI rather than from conda repositories.